# Bluemix `docker exec` returns 404

Tags: mysql, docker, ibm-cloud

I pushed an image (`mysql:5.5` to be exact) to my registry and am currently running the container under the name `db` and it does appear when I run `cf ic ps`.

As `docker exec` seems to be supported now, I tried to run `cf ic exec -it db bash` but I get a response of `Error response from daemon: 404 error encountered while processing request!`. Any `exec` command I try results in the same error... Does anyone know why this returns a 404 when my container does exist?

For reference I need to load a dump onto the container which is why I'm trying `docker exec` in the first place.
[image: terminal]

Edit: Can confirm this occurs for any container I create and try to `exec -it` into. `logs` for any container give the same error as well

Comment: Could you please let me know what version of docker and cf ic do you have?

Answer (score 1):

For some reasons the daemon could not reach your container. I've just tried the following command on different kinds of containers and it worked:

> cf ic exec -it [*containerId*] [*command*]

I think you should retry. If the problem persists I suggest you to restart the container with:

> cf ic restart [*containerId*]

If you still get 404 you could try with a new container instance using *docker run* again.

Moreover, be sure that you have installed the latest version of the [IBM Containers CLI](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_cli_ov.html)

Answer (score 0):

Due to a platform issue this command, even though recently added to the docker's supported commands on Bluemix, was not working fine. This was a bug that's been resolved few days ago so you should try again.